# Regular Expression that Matches Any Number or Letter or Dash

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Given `searchString = "23423asdfa-''"`

This regular expression should evaluate to false but it does not! Any ideas?

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"[\w-]*");
rgx.IsMatch(searchString)
```

Comment: Ahh lost the two apostrophes at the end in the double quote. Yeah, JaredPar's answer should cover it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because you haven't constrained it to match the entire string.  Hence it is allowed to consider matches on subsets of the string.  A very large subset of the string matches the data hence the regex returns true.

Try the following to force it to match the entire input.

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^[\w-]*$");
rgx.IsMatch(searchString)
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was forgetting something really simple.

Answer (score 2):

You need to anchor your expression.  If you don't, then if any substring of the input matches, the regex match is considered successful.  Change the regex to "^[\w-]*$" where the ^ and $ will match the beginning and end of the string, respectively.